# Onclick with parameters - Javascript does not recognize it

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am trying to send a function with a parameter on onclick but javascript doesn't seem to recognize it (the type possibly). 
Onclick:

```
 onclick="sortAsc('department')"
```

Function:

```
function sortAsc(str){
        members.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.str > b.str;
        });
        members.sort();
        angular.element(document.getElementById('cntl')).scope().$apply();
}
```

So, *str* is supposed to be part of an array in javascript. For example in this case *str* converts to *department*,  therefore converting the code in:

```
return a.department > b.department;
```

I've tried adding and removing the double/single quotes around the parameter when sending it on onclick, it doesn't work.

I would very much appreciate if someone explained to me why this  doesn't work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It should be not `a.str`, but `a[str]`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: bracket notation can be used to dynamically access properties during runtime based on a string value